# how to stop an animation loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The code below basicly animates a div back and forth. Then I want the animation to stop while hovering. It works if I remove this line: "$(".block").animate({left: '0px'}, 1, animate);" but then the div just animates once wich is not what I want. So how do keep the .stop() functionality but still get the animation to loop in infinity ?

```
$(function animate(){
$(".block").animate({left: '+=500px'}, 2000);
$(".block").animate({left: '0px'}, 1, animate);
});

$(".block").hover(function(){
$(".block").stop();
$(".block").animate({ width:"20%", height:"20%"}, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated**

Not sure if:

```
$(".block").stop( true, true );
```

is what your looking for.

The first `true` clears the queue and the last `true` jumps to the end of the animation queue, effectively ending the animation.

```
$(".block").stop( true );
```

This would clear the queue but NOT skip to the end.

Comment: $(".block").stop( true ); does the same thing, and is short, the last options defaults to false so is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try writing another function on $(".block").mouseleave() and call animate inside it. This will be triggered when your mouse leaves the div.
May be you also try the combination of mouseenter and mouseleave as well.
In your case its working fine and stopping the animation as soon as your entering the div area, but there is no function to tell what to do when it comes out of it.
I had a similar problem where I was fading an image on mouseover....it works well trying the above.

Hope this helps!